# SonarQube complains about using ResponseEntity with a wildcard

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, sonarqube

I use SpringBoot for REST web services development and SonarQube for static analysis.

I have a few endpoints in my application that look the following way:

```
@PostMapping
ResponseEntity<?> addSomething(@RequestBody Some object) {
    // some code there
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

SonarQube complains about using ResponseEntity with a wildcard, reporting me a **Critical issue "Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters"**.

I wonder if I should disable this verification in SonarQube or come up with something different for return type for these cases.

What do you think about it?

Comment: well imho, in that case, i would use the interface Serializable, as i normally want to return an object, which can be serialized

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Finally I've removed `<?>` from return value, so the code looks like the following now:

```
@PostMapping
ResponseEntity addSomething(@RequestBody Some object) {
    // some code there
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

SonarQube doesn't complain anymore and code seems a little bit simpler now.

Comment: In this case the message changes in: "Provide the parametrized type for this generic."

Answer (score 6):

```
@PostMapping
ResponseEntity<Object> addSomething(@RequestBody Some object) {
    // some code there
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

This will also remove the error. It is still very generic, but it is one of the solutions if you want to return different types based on the outcome. For instance:

```
@PostMapping
    ResponseEntity<Object> addSomething(@RequestBody Some object) {

        //Will return ResponseEntity<> with errors
        ResponseEntity<Object> errors = mapValidationService(bindingResult);
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(errors)) return errors;
        
        // some code there
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So actually i find the rule pretty self describing:

> Using a wildcard as a return type implicitly means that the return value should be considered read-only, but without any way to enforce this contract.
>
> Let's take the example of method returning a "List". Is it possible on this list to add a Dog, a Cat, ... we simply don't know. The consumer of a method should not have to deal with such disruptive questions.
>
> https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1452

So Actually in your case, you do not want any kind of Class in there, you specifically want an `Serializable`-object - for obvious reasons: it should be serialized later on

So instead of using `?` it would be more suitable in your case to use `Serializable`. This is always case dependent, but normally you definitly expect some kind of common interface or base class as a return value. Hence that, the follow up developer, definitly knows what he can expect, and what kind of functionality he definitly can use.

Comment: Updated a question. I use ResponseEntity<?> return type in order to return particular status code depending on the logic implemented in my controller.
In this case RepsonseEntity replace T parameter with "Object" that is not Serializable by itself.
So Serializable is not a very good choice in this situation.

Comment: infact HttpStatus implements Serializable: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html