# What's the reason to use ResponseEntity<?> return type instead of simple ResponseEntity in Spring Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, sonarqube

I've seen a lot of examples of Spring Controllers implementation that use `ResponseEntity<?>` in order to return HTTP response that have a specific status code and optional body.

`ResponseEntity<?>` notation is present even in official Spring tutorials like the following one: [Building REST services with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)

What's the reason to use `ResponseEntity<?>` instead of simple `ResponseEntity`?

It's a little bit related to my previous question: [SonarQube complains about using ResponseEntity with a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974384/sonarqube-complains-about-using-responseentity-with-a-wildcard)

There is some explanation in [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) thread, but I'd like to pay more attention to ResponseEntity class and it's use in Spring Controllers.

Consider the following snippet of code where `somethingService` returns an `Optional` of `Something` class:

```
@GetMapping
ResponseEntity<?> getSomething() {
    return somethingService.getSomething()
               .map(smth -> new ResponseEntity<>(smth, HttpStatus.OK))        
               .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

Is there any reason to leave a wildcard even if I don't get any profit from compiler checks since `ResponseEntity(HttpStatus status)` parametrises `ResponseEntity` with `Object` class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: I use it sometimes in case of an error. I response an particular error object.

Comment: @g00glen00b updated a question to make it more concrete.

Comment: @Patrick added a use case from my code that I'm concerned about

Comment: @IlyaZinkovich without the wildcard `<?>` you would be working with raw types (`ResponseEntity`)  right? So I think that the duplicate is still valid?

Comment: @g00glen00b the duplicate doesn't explain any profit in using generic types in this particular case where I use ResponseEntity with optional body. Using generic <?> seems rational for examples in the duplicate, but here I think it only adds redundant complexity and clutters the code. (and it appears in many tutorials without any explanation)

Comment: Techically it will work just fine without the wildcard, but don't you get a compiler warning when you leave it out? That's basically the main reason to apply generics where requested even when you don't really benefit from it, to not end up with piles of warnings about raw types.

Comment: @Gimby no, there is no compiler warning without a wildcard.

Comment: Your question was already answered :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549379/when-use-responseentityt-and-restcontroller-for-spring-restful-applications?rq=1

Comment: @MirkoBalmaceda nope.